# How to check at least one Payment Method is added in Stripe Flutter?

Tags: flutter, payment

I'm integrating Stripe into my Flutter app and able to show the Customer Sheet and the Payment Sheet. However, to allow the user to navigate to a particular page, I want to ensure that the user has added at least one Payment Method or Card. I can use the Customer Sheet to make the user add or select a Payment Method but I'm not been able to check if there's a card or payment method already added or not.

Can someone tell me how can I check it in my Flutter app?